# How to use HTMLTable in UiBinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Why there're no info about how to use HTMLTable in UiBinder on the internet?

I tried this simple code:

```
           <g:HTMLTable>
               <g:row>
                   <c:cell>
                       <b>My Info</b>
                   </c:cell>
               </g:row>
           </g:HTMLTable>
```

After ran, it showed `No class matching "row" in urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui: <g:row>` error.

Is there anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing said because there's to say.

To begin with, `HTMLTable` is an abstract class, base of `FlexTable` and `Grid`. `FlexTable` cannot have its children configured via UiBinder, contrary to `Grid` (and this is documented in its javadoc).

If you're going to change the contents of the table dynamically after it's constructed, then you can use a `Grid` (or `FlexTable`). Otherwise, there's no reason to use such widgets, just put a `<table>` within an `HTMLPanel`.

Comment: I want to use Table to layout simple 3 column lay out: Name Label-Name TextBox - Search Button, but the Css expert said using <table> for layout is bad. Also i afraid of it can cause some quirks when running on the older browsers.
Is it good to use Grid to do that Layout?

Comment: `Grid` is a table, so if you think (or anyone tells you) you shouldn't use tables for layout, then don't use `Grid` either.

Comment: That is why i heard some people said do not use VericalPanel, HorizontalPanel, Grid.. which  can create some quirks in other browsers. Google suggests to use DockLayoutPanel, SplitLayoutPanel,... (or anyclass that has word "Layout") for layout. So i don't think Grid is a good choice. Grid should be used for presenting data only.

Comment: To present data, `CellTable` is generally more appropriate. But really, use what fits you best at the moment, know what you do (i.e. learn about the CSS quirks and make conscious decisions, don't just listen to what people say you should do), and don't hesitate to refactor your code later on (when you'll know more and understand what you did wrong and what you could have done better).